# navigate to section from link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React component:

```
<Route exact path="/terms-and-conditions" component={PrivacyStatement} />
```

**PrivacyStatement.js**

```
const PrivacyStatement = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <PrivacyStatementDetail />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default PrivacyStatement;
```

**PrivacyStatementDetail.js**

```
const PrivacyStatementDetail = () => {
  return (
      <>
        <section className='support-content ptb-120'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-between'>
              <div className='col-lg-4 col-md-4 d-none d-md-block d-lg-block'>
                <div className='support-article-sidebar sticky-sidebar'>
                    <button
                        className='nav-link'
                        data-bs-target='#support-tab-7'
                        data-bs-toggle='pill'
                        type='button'
                        role='tab'
                        aria-selected='false'
                    >
                      Privacy Notice
                    </button>
                    <button
                        className='nav-link'
                        data-bs-target='#support-tab-8'
                        data-bs-toggle='pill'
                        type='button'
                        role='tab'
                        aria-selected='false'
                    >
                      Cookie Policy
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='col-lg-7 col-md-8'>
                <div className='tab-content' id='v-pills-supportContent'>                        
                  <div
                      className='tab-pane fade'
                      id='support-tab-7'
                      role='tabpanel'
                  >
                    <div className='support-article-wrap'>
                      <h2>Privacy Notice</h2>
                      <ul className='support-article-list list-unstyled'>
                         ...........
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                      className='tab-pane fade'
                      id='support-tab-8'
                      role='tabpanel'
                  >
                    <div className='support-article-wrap'>
                      <h2>Cookie Policy</h2>
                      <ul className='support-article-list list-unstyled'>
                         .......
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </>
  );
};

export default PrivacyStatementDetail;
```

Into `PrivacyStatementDetail` I have different tabs. How I can navigate the user directly to

`terms-and-conditions#support-tab-8` when the link with tab number is clicked from the routes?

Comment: You mean when you click on these buttons inside `PrivacyStatementDetail`?

Comment: no, when I click on the router link.

Comment: I guess you are using `react-router@5.*`. With (`useLocation`)[https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation]. You can get (`location`)[https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location] which includes `hash`.

Comment: can you show me code example please?